# Nodejs routing does not point to all inner routes of Angular App

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, frontend

I am building a frontend application on Angular 9. To serve the application, I am using a NodeJs server to accept all requests and point them to the Dist (Build) files Angular generates.

**Problem statement**

All routes received by Node server should be forwarded to the Angular Application files.

**Problem I'm facing**

When I try to use some inner route from the Node server it returns a 404 response. But the page works when I run Angular in development mode.

For example, `localhost:4200/innerPage` (Angular Dev Server) works but `localhost:8000/innerPage` (Node Server) does not work.

The Angular page is rendered when I visit `localhost:8000` though. Only the internal routes for Angular are not working on the server.

NodeJS code is

```
const app = express();


app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "../../dist/TournamentsPlatform/"));

app.listen(8000, () => console.log("Server started on port 8000"));
```

**What I have tried earlier**

`app.get("/", function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../dist/TournamentsPlatform/"));
 });`

`app.use("/*", express.static(__dirname + "../../dist/TournamentsPlatform/"));`

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + "../../dist/TournamentsPlatform/"));`

**Error - the browser console shows**

`Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

**Misc Info**

- I am using Lazy loading for all Angular routes. Each page is a new module
- The page works fine when I internally route to it. So, when I go to `localhost:8000/` (NodeJS Server) and then click on the link that points to the inner route, it works fine. And at that time, the browser URL is `localhost:8000/innerPage`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```js
// fulfill the array with extensions that are part of what an angular
// app must need during load like: .js, .png, .jpg, .woff, .json etc
const allowedExtensions = ['.js'];

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (allowedExtensions.some(ext => req.url.includes(ext))) {
    // remove the forward slash at the end of the path 
    const url = req.url.replace(/\/$/,'');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'TournamentsPlatform', url));
  } else {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'TournamentsPlatform', 'index.html'));
  }
});
```

BTW, this won't work unless the first request brings `index.html` explicitly in the path (e.g. `http://localhost/index.html`), because express won't know the default file to serve:

```js
app.get('*', 
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'TournamentsPlatform'));
```

Comment: Same error. 
I'm starting to believe, its something wrong in Angular.

Comment: Updated my answer. I've built something to test over here and I was missing the .js files (if I'd like to serve them, I must send them when required, instead of sending `index.html` again).

Comment: Don’t worry, nothing wrong with Angular. You should set it up in a way so that all requests are routed to index.html, expect for requests that have existing folders/files.

Answer (score 0):

Removing this line from app.js works

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + "../../dist/TournamentsPlatform/"));`

Comment: I do not have this line in App.js currently. 
Can you please explain a bit more on the approach ?

Comment: But you mentioned in the post that you are using this line of code.

Comment: I had tried that and it did not work. The current Nodejs code is pasted too. 
I'll update the section for even more clarity.
Apoligies :)